# How to add dll's using py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I use a c++ dll in python. That dll uses other dlls.

I want to know if it's possible to include all the dll's in my .exe using py2exe without calling them directlly. If so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need a `data_files=` referencing all of those DLLs, perhaps with a wildcard.  See [the docs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step521) for an example (about specifically the MS runtime DLL).  Note, as the docs say a million times, that you need legal rights to redistribute DLLs and those need to be obtained from the DLL's authors/owners -- don't just *assume* it's legally OK to redistribute them!-)